# aws-sdk crashing nodejs program

Tags: node.js, express, aws-sdk

I am using aws-sdk for javascript.

The code below works fine when using in a stand-alone program

```
//program.js

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const firehose = new AWS.Firehose({
   accessKeyId: "XXX",
  secretAccessKey: "YY"
});

const params = {
  DeliveryStreamName: 'demo1',
  Record: {
    Data: new Buffer("Hello World")
  }
};

firehose.putRecord(params, function (err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Again, the above code works fine as a stand alone file. Data gets pushed into firehose and then further down to Redshift. 
so if i execute

```
node program.js
```

I am able to see my data in Redshift. Yay!!

=============================

However, what i really want to achieve is to push data to firehose when a certain route gets hit in my express application. So I take the exact same code as above and stick it in my route

```
// router.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const firehose = new AWS.Firehose({
   accessKeyId: "XXX",
  secretAccessKey: "YY"
});

router
  .get('/v1/locations/:id?', (req, res) => {

   const params = {
     DeliveryStreamName: 'demo1',
     Record: {
        Data: new Buffer("Hello World")
     }
   };

    firehose.putRecord(params, function (err, data){
     if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       return;
     }
      console.log(data);           

    });

   // do the work that needs to be done for this route and send a response
   res.send("some data");  

  });
```

The minute  firehose.putRecord is executed .. it crashes my program with the following error:

```

```
TypeError: doneCallback.cal is not a function
    at Request.callListeners (/api-project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
    at callNextListener (/api-project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:95:12)
    at /api-project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:74:9
    at finish (/api-project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:315:7)
    at /api-project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:333:9
    at Credentials.get (/api-project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:126:7)
    at getAsyncCredentials (/api-project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:327:24)
    at Config.getCredentials (/api-project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:347:9)
    at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (/api-project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:69:26)
    at Request.callListeners (/api-project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:101:18)
```

I can't understand why this code crashes my express program. is this is bug in the aws-sdk library or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Finally figured out the issue. aws-sdk had not installed properly (i wonder how this could happen). in the file sequential_executor.js on line 115 .. there is a statement **doneCallback.call ** ... however in my file that statement was only **doneCallback.cal**   ..

Answer (score 1):

You should be sending the express response inside your success callback.

```
firehose.putRecord(params, function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
     console.log(err);
     return;
   }
    console.log(data);           
    res.send("some data");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, your `res.send(data)` will effectively exit the program and send data. However, your `putRecord` callback is the time when your exit should occur. In node, things do not happen in a sequence from top to bottom of the code, but instead it executes in order of the callback events. so the execution flow for your code would be like this:

1. file executes
2. some operation is performed
3. callback for operation occurs
4. then if theres additional code outside of operate, it will continue, otherwise the code will exit in that callback. Hence, put the `res.send` in your `putRecord` callback.

Comment: res.send(data) should not exit the program. After all this is a express server running 24/7 . Since putRecord is a async activity, i believe it gets pushed onto the eventQueue and the callback should get executed whenever this event completes.